# How to count occurrences of different values in multiple columns all at once where number or name of columns is not known?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe that gets generated automatically and the names and numbers of columns will never be known. I would like to know how I can count the occurrence of each of the values in each of the columns.

For example,

```
        Col1  Col2   Col3
Row1    True  False  False
Row2    True  True   True
Row3    False False  True
Row4    False False  False
```

The result should be something like:

```
Col1 Count Col2 Count Col3 Count
True   2   True    1  True   2
False  2   False   3  False  2
```

I have tried applying GroupBy kind of like this:

```
df.groupBy(record => (record.Col1, record.Col2, record.Col3)).count().show
```

But this wouldn't work for me since I wouldn't know the number or names of the columns.

Comment: You can try inspect schema at runtime. `df.schema`. See [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType).

Comment: Also, I don't think it's possible to count multiple columns at once, since it's not how group by and aggregation works. If it's acceptable, you can count multiple times, one column a time, then `union` the result dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

### Load the test data provided

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |Col1  Col2   Col3
        |True  False  False
        |True  True   True
        |False False  True
        |False False  False
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS2 = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\s+").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString("|"))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df2 = spark.read
      .option("sep", "|")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS2)
    df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()
    /**
      * +-----+-----+-----+
      * |Col1 |Col2 |Col3 |
      * +-----+-----+-----+
      * |true |false|false|
      * |true |true |true |
      * |false|false|true |
      * |false|false|false|
      * +-----+-----+-----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Col1: boolean (nullable = true)
      * |-- Col2: boolean (nullable = true)
      * |-- Col3: boolean (nullable = true)
      */
```

### Simple way to compute the count for each distinct values in the column

```scala
 val findCounts = df2.columns.flatMap(c => Seq(col(c), count(c).over(Window.partitionBy(c)).as(s"count_$c")))
    df2.select(findCounts: _*).distinct()
      .show(false)
    /**
      * +-----+----------+-----+----------+-----+----------+
      * |Col1 |count_Col1|Col2 |count_Col2|Col3 |count_Col3|
      * +-----+----------+-----+----------+-----+----------+
      * |false|2         |false|3         |false|2         |
      * |false|2         |false|3         |true |2         |
      * |true |2         |false|3         |false|2         |
      * |true |2         |true |1         |true |2         |
      * +-----+----------+-----+----------+-----+----------+
      */
```

### If you need in the same format as mentioned, try this

> Assuming all the columns in the dataframe have same distinct values

```scala
// Assuming all the columns in the dataframe have same distinct values
    val columns = df2.columns
    val head = columns.head
    val zeroDF = df2.groupBy(head).agg(count(head).as(s"${head}_count"))
    columns.tail.foldLeft(zeroDF){
      (df, c) => df.join(df2.groupBy(c).agg(count(c).as(s"${c}_count")), col(head) === col(c))
    }.show(false)

    /**
      * +-----+----------+-----+----------+-----+----------+
      * |Col1 |Col1_count|Col2 |Col2_count|Col3 |Col3_count|
      * +-----+----------+-----+----------+-----+----------+
      * |false|2         |false|3         |false|2         |
      * |true |2         |true |1         |true |2         |
      * +-----+----------+-----+----------+-----+----------+
      */
```